# Math 'Example' formatting

Tags: macros

I have a simple macro that takes an input and bold prints **Example** followed by the input then a line break. Except it breaks after the first [ with no bold.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\exm}[1]{\textbf{Example{#1}}\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{exm} [6.1]
    This is an example
\end{exm}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\exm` definition had mandatory argument, not optional. This means, that when you use it, it had to be written as `\exm{6.1}`:

[image]

For above image I slightly change your MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\exm}[1]{\par\noindent\textbf{Example~#1}\\}
\begin{document}
\exm{6.1}
    This is an example\\
\end{document}
```

As you can see, it is used as command (as it is defined) and not as environment as you did.

Comment: Should there be a `\par` directive before `\noindent`?

Comment: @Mico, yes, this will make use of command more safe. (always in new line). However, correct solution for OP needs is suggestion in your answer :-)

Answer (score 7):

Since you've defined a macro, not an environment, the way to invoke it is to write

```
\exm{6.1}
```

However, it looks to me like you *do* want to create a standalone environment, possibly like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{exm}[1]{%
  \par  % start a new paragraph
  \bigskip  % insert some vertical whitespace
  \noindent % no paragraph indentation
  \textbf{Example #1}}{%
  \par\bigskip % insert another paragraph break and more vert. whitespace
}

\begin{document}
\begin{exm}{6.1}
    This is an example.
\end{exm}

\end{document}
```

It'll produce the following output:

[image]

Comment: +1. I've accepted Zarko's answer, but I'll consider this for the project. Thx.